# Assign a RewriteBase / for every directory under docroot

Tags: mod-rewrite

HI:

I'm trying to assign by default a RewriteBase / directive for every folder under docroot folder.

Do you know how to do it ?

I've tried using a

```
<Directory "/docroot/*">RewriteBase *</Directory>
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Thank yoU !

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: i want to setup several cakephp applications under custom folders, and remove the .htaccess dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`<DirectoryMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch) instead:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/docroot/">
    RewriteBase /
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Note that `<DirectoryMatch>` is only allowed in the [server configuration and virtual host context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you know how to set a custom rewritebase for every folder, based in their folder name, for example, rewritebase /folder1/ for directory folder1, rewritebase /fodler2/ for /folder2 and so on ?

Comment: @user365877: That’s the default: “The default setting is; `RewriteBase physical-directory-path`” (see [`RewriteBase` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)).